# Program keeps telling that number I wrote isn't integer

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I made a program and it constantly tells me that the number I input isn't an integer.

I'm entering `100010110101` and it pops up with this error:

[image]

code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  m,lo,cshl,cdhl,cjhl,csl,cdl,cjl:integer;
begin
  m := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  cshl := m div 100000000000;
  cdhl := m div 10000000000 mod 10;
  cjhl := m div 10000000000 mod 100;
  csl := m div 1000000000 mod 1000;
  cdl := m div 100000000 mod 10000;
  cjl := m div 10000000 mod 100000;
  lo := cjl + cdl * 10 + csl * 100 + cjhl * 1000 + cdhl * 10000 + cshl  *100000;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(lo));
end;
```

Comment: That is larger than MAXINT.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the error meesage is correct?  That is, the number isn't within the range of valid 32-bit integers.

Comment: `StrToInt()` fails because `100010110101` requires 37 bits, exceeding the capacity of a 32-bit `Integer`.

Comment: No. The program is NOT telling you that the number is not an integer! It is telling you that the number is not a VALID integer value. Do you see the difference?

Comment: In general, you have to think about the data you're storing in the memory via variables. Think about heap allocations, which are the biggest bottleneck when trying to produce fast code. Anyway, the point is to think about how different data types require different structures / sizes of memory. Everything has a limitation. Even strings - basically the limit is the size of the computer's available RAM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider how Delphi (and most languages) handle 32-bit integers: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit#Range_for_storing_integers)

In this context, `Integer` is a 32-bit integer, and any value less than `-2,147,483,648` or greater than `2,147,483,647` IS NOT a valid 32-bit integer.

The "common sense" would indicate, that integers range from `-∞` to `+∞`, but that is not the case in computer architecture.

Use `Int64` if you want to "cover" more values.

In your case, the code should look like this:

```
var
  m,lo,cshl,cdhl,cjhl,csl,cdl,cjl:Int64;
begin
  m := StrToInt64(Edit1.Text);
  ...
end;
```

Cheers

Comment: You should use  : m:=StrToInt64(Edit1.Text); instead of : m:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text); (consider also: : m:=StrToInt64Def(Edit1.Text,0);